# Prevent Default Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I am working on a music player and i believe my prevent default is not working. When I hit play everything works fine. The button switches to the pause button and the music plays. However when I hit pause the page refreshes. Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
play.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    song.play();
    $(play).replaceWith('<a class="button gradient" id="pause" href="" title=""></a>');
    container.addClass('containerLarge');
    cover.addClass('coverLarge');

});

pause.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
container.removeClass('containerLarge');
    cover.removeClass('coverLarge');
    song.pause();
    $('#pause').replaceWith('<a class="button gradient" id="play" href="" title=""></a>');

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're replacing the elements with new ones. The event handlers are bound to the *old* elements, not the new ones, and the references stored in variables `play` and `pause` will be the old detached DOM elements as well.

You need to leave the elements alone, and programatically hide/show them, rather than completely removing them and replacing them with the other element:

```
play.on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  play.hide();
  pause.show();
});
```

Comment: Or use on like this: `$('body').on('click','#pause',function(e){`

Comment: While I provided an answer below, I can't see why you would need to removed the DOM elements entirely. So @Meagar's answer is better. You should simply hide the elements not removed them from the DOM. However if you NEED to remove them and add them back, adding the listener to the body element and seeing where the event took place would be an option.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click','#pause',function(e){
$('body').on('click','#play',function(e){
```

You didn't provide HTML but these should work.